# Angular 8 - nested ngFor is extremely slow

Tags: angular, performance, multidimensional-array, ngfor

I am trying to display 2d array by 2 nested ngFor

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="!calculating" style="margin: auto;">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-2">
      <div class="row" *ngFor="let pixelRow of pixels" style="width: max-content;">
        <div class="col pixel" 
        *ngFor="let pixel of pixelRow"  
        [ngStyle]="{'background-color': pixel.Color }"
        (click)="changePixelState(pixel.xIndex, pixel.yIndex)"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Basically it works fine on normal scale of data, but when it been defined as 1000X1000 - It takes huge time to be display and meanwhile the page is not responsive.
I have tried to use cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport but i couldn't find any documentation of how to use it on 2d array, only on one list of data.

What can I do? any Ideas?

Comment: `What can I do? any Ideas?` ← Limit your data. You can add paging (or scrolling) and then only load a page of data. That is a very normal mechanism for handling / displaying larger sets of data. No person can "consume" 1000x1000 of data at any given time so it is not necessary for the application to display that data.

Comment: Well, I have to agree with your point that no one can consume that amount of that data at once. Pagination would be good idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can always overwrite the trackBy of the ngFor providing your own implementation can speed up performance,

1- Inject a unique Identifier in each of your object an Id or Guid

2- Use the unique identifier in your teackBy method

3- In your template html bind the trackBy method

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of collection;trackBy: trackByFn">{{item.id}}</li>
</ul>
```

4- In your ts file

```
trackByFn(index, item) {
   return item.id;}
```

Now when you change the collection, Angular can track which items have been added or removed according to the unique identifier and create or destroy only the items that changed.

Comment: This will have no impact on initial rendering performance whatsoever.

Comment: Yes you are right , I have to agree with you displaying one million records in a page no one implements it like that , a lazy loading or even simple paging will improve performance but in case for instance someone decided to display 1K per page, still the track by will help in the page responsiveness

Comment: No, it will not. trackBy is helpful when re-rendering items, but makes no difference during the initial render.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following lazy loading virtual scroller component load data in batches 
[PrimeNG Virtual Scroller](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/virtualscroller)